# How do I pass data between React Functional Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, react-functional-component

Currently, I am trying to pass a specific piece of data, the user's `name`, from one functional component, the `<User/>` component, to another, the `<Profile />` component, when the user navigates to a certain page.

Here is my code:

**User.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function User(props) {
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to={`/${props.username}`}>
                <hr />
                <p>
                    ({props.name}) {props.username}
                </p>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(User));
```

**UsersList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import User from './User';

function UsersList() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <User username="john_smith" name="John Smith"/>
      <User username="james_madison" name="James Madison"/>
      <User username="george_washington" name="George Washington"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default (withRouter(UsersList));
```

**Feed.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import UsersList from "./users/UsersList";

function Feed() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <UsersList/>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Feed from './components/Feed';
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import Root from "./Root";


function App() {
  return (
    <Root>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
        <Route exact path="/:username" component={Profile} />
      </Switch>
    </Root>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is the current `<Profile />` page - I simply want to pass the user's name, **not the username**, into a pair of `<h1></h1>` tags:

**Profile.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

function Profile(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>I SIMPLY WANT TO PASS THE USERS NAME HERE</h1>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

I appreciate any help or direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Redux. This is how I sloved it-

First install redux module: npm install react-redux

### src/components/Profile.js

Map the user data which is in redux store using mapStateToProps function

```
  import React from "react";
  import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 function Profile( props) {
 let users = props.users
 let userName = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
 var name;
  users.forEach((element) => {
   if(element['username'] === userName){
   name = element['name'];
 }
 });
   return (
   <Container>
     <h1>I SIMPLY WANT TO PASS THE USERS NAME HERE</h1>
     {name }
   </Container>
    );
  }
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   users: state.users,
   });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
```

### /src/action.js

Here I have initialized all the user initial values, ideally the user data you will get from another system, in such case you will use Thunk or Saga for side effect operations

```
   export const LOAD_USER = 'LOAD_USER';

 const users = [{ username:'john_smith', name: 'John Smith' }, 
            { username:'james_madison', name: 'James Madison' }, 
            {username:'george_washington', name: 'George Washington'}];

   export const loadeUser = () => ({
   type: LOAD_USER,
   payload: { users },
   });
```

### /src/reducer.js

I am simply passing all the user data to the state object

```
     import { LOAD_USER } from './actions';

    export const users = (state = [], action) => {
   const { type, payload } = action;
   switch (type) {
   case LOAD_USER :{
    const { users } = payload;
    return users;
   }
   default:
    return state;
  }
  }
```

### /src/components/User.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 function User({user}) {
  return (
    <div>
        <Link to={`/${user.username}`}>
            <hr />
            <p>
                ({user.name}) {user.username}
            </p>
        </Link>
    </div>
    )
  }
  export default User;
```

### /src/components/UsersList.js

Here we have to use both mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps so that dispatch action is executed on a load of the component via useEffect hook.

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { loadeUser } from '../actions';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import User from './User';


  function UsersList({ users = [] , startLoadingUsers}) {
   useEffect(() => {
   startLoadingUsers();
   }, []);

 return (
  <div>
  <h1>Users</h1>
  { 
    users.map(user => <User user={user} />)
  }
  </div>
  );
 }

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  users: state.users,
 });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 startLoadingUsers: () => dispatch(loadeUser()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
(withRouter(UsersList));
```

### /src/App.js

Use the BrowserRouter to wrap around the different routes

```
   import React from "react";
  import { Route, Switch,BrowserRouter as Router, } 
   from "react-router-dom";
  import Feed from './components/Feed';
   import Profile from "./components/Profile";

   function App() {
   return (
   <Router>
     <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
      <Route exact path="/:username" component={Profile} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
   );
  }
 export default App;
```

### /src/index.js

Finally, hook the store as a wrapper around App component so that all the components can use Redux store and that is done by Provider.

```
       import React from 'react';
       import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
       import App from './App';
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
       import { configureStore } from './store';

       const store = configureStore();

       ReactDOM.render(
       <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
       </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
       );
```

### /src/store.js

```
        import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
        import { users } from './reducer';

         const reducers = {
         users,
         };

        const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
        export const configureStore = () =>
         createStore(
           rootReducer,
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
        );
```

And the final result

[image]

Comment: @anks, good to hear that, pls accept this answer :)

Comment: don't have enough reputation to - I tried though!

Comment: @anks https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where a global state manager would be of use. Consider something like `redux` or `context providers`. As far as functional components go, more people are moving away from redux and using context providers with the `useContext` hook ([more information can be found here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)). As far as quick solutions, using the `App` state is always possible, but passing props can become really messy when trying to get them to the same level of the component hierarchy.